# What is the “and” and “or” Operator in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I used an || operator within the Kotlin IDEA but was throwing an error. This confused me, one of the first queries when searching google was a closed stack overflow thread with a snarky "answer" comment which wasn't helpful.

The first query in google hit is some function "or" gibberish.
My code:

```
if(inputAmount >= 0 || inputAmount = -99)
```

I understand what is "wrong". there was some logic errors the second part of the "if" statement should have been inputAmount == -99. In my case, the code needed to further be adjusted because of the actual type that was being used.

```
if(inputAmount >= 0.0 || inputAmount.toInt() == -99)
```

This appears to be different then other languages in that other languages just simply allow you to have your "logic" error with the "inputAmount = -99". So the '||' operator is allowed and is similar to most other languages.

So first step if encounter this error is to make sure your logic is correct. (check)

infix functions > sense according to the documentation "or" and "and" are infix functions that don't use the short circuit, is it technically wrong to call the "||" operator an "or" operator and should be called logical 'or'?

when referring to the infix 'or' how do people refer to that in Kotlin?

Comment: What exactly is your question? `=` is an assignment, `==` checks for equality.  You basically have: if my input amount is equal or bigger to 0 OR my input amount assigned to -99 (doesn't yield in a bool, thus not valid)

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. The || operator seems to have little to do with the errors you have. First your missing a `=` in the equality comparison. Second kotlin doesn't do type conversions for you. If you need a double literal then it's `-99.0`

Comment: Guess i should be really calling things like '|' or '&' bitwise '|' or bitwise '&'

Comment: Yes I understand that assignment is = and == is equality. As explained that doesn't really say why the compiler wasn't allowing the || part. Other languages also do implicit conversions. I don't have questions per say, just trying to be helpful to beginners because Kotlin functions differently then other languages. Other language would have just compiled with the "=" assignment and done implicit conversions. I've always just called "||" and "|" "or" operators, one does short circuit the other doesn't. my search came to stack overflow and the previous question was locked with poor answers.

Comment: In your first statement, the `||` is not allowed because an assignment does not evaluate to a Boolean. Only `Booleans` can be combined with `||`. If you change the assignment operator to the equality operator, then the compiler will not complain about `||` but it will complain about comparing a Float to an Int.

Comment: in boolean logic takes statements. A=b is a statement that is always true. This is why don't use stack overflow. other languages allow this, i'm pretty sure at least old C++ compilers did.

Comment: Not to get caught up in the coding which was more support, as previously asked: when referring to the infix function 'or' how do Kotlin folk typically refer to that?  sense according to the documentation "or" and "and" are infix functions that don't use the short circuit, is it technically wrong to call the "||" operator an "or" operator and should be called logical 'or'? I've always just called both "||" and "|" "or" operators and known that one does short circuit and one doesn't. "|" doesn't seem available, just the infix function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in boolean logic takes statements. A=b is a statement that is always true

No, it isn't. In C, C++ and Java it's an expression, and its value is the value of `b`. If `b` is false, it's false, if `b` is 10, it's 10. And you really don't want to confuse "statements" in programming languages with "statements" in logic; they are entirely different things.

Separately, C and C++ (but not Java) allow `||` to work on all integral types, and not just booleans (because they didn't originally have booleans as a separate type).

> when referring to the infix function 'or' how do Kotlin folk typically refer to that?

Bitwise or for integral types, and I've never actually seen anyone use non-short-circuiting `or` on booleans, but if I had to I'd call it... well, non-short-circuiting `or`.

> is it technically wrong to call the "||" operator an "or" operator and should be called logical 'or'

Both `||` and `or` (on booleans) are "logical 'or'" and I don't see any problem with calling them simply 'or'. If you need to distinguish use short-circuiting vs non-short-circuiting. But again, I've never actually ran into a use of the non-short-circuiting version.

Comment: thanks Alexey for your comments I tried to up the vote but it wouldn't allow me. =)

Comment: you are correct about the expression part too, not always true, just checked, but it does compile if (a=b) is put in parenthesis to form an expression and it will if true go to the next section..